# SwiftUI - disclosure group expanding behaviour - keep top item static

Tags: swift, drop-down-menu, swiftui, expandablelistview, disclosure

I'm trying to create a drop down menu using swift UI. I'm actually implementing this into a UIKit project.

The basic functionality I am going for should be that the user clicks on a label with a certain data unit on it and a list expands with other units of measure that can be selected.

Here is my SwiftUI code:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 14.0.0, *)
struct DataUnitDropDown: View {
    var units = ["ltr", "usg", "impg"]
    
    @State private var selectedDataUnit = 0
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
            DisclosureGroup(units[selectedDataUnit], isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< units.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("\(units[index])")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .padding(.all)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedDataUnit = index
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.isExpanded.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a couple of questions here. Firstly, ideally I wanted to place this into an existing horizontal UIStackView. However,  the issue I have is that obviously once the dropdown expands, it increases the height of the stack, which is not what I want. Here is a screen shot of the component (see 'ltr'):

[image]

When expanded in the stackView:

[image]

So I reluctantly placed it in the main view adding some autolayout constraints:

```
    if #available(iOS 14.0.0, *) {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: DataUnitDropDown())
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: refuelInfoView.actualUpliftVolume.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        controller.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: refuelInfoView.actualUpliftVolume.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

But now when I expand, the whole menu shifts up:

[image]

Clearly not what I am looking for.

So I suppose my question is 2-fold:

1- Is there any way I can incorporate this element into an existing stack view without the stack increasing in height when the dropdown is expanded? (I guess not!)

2- If I have to add this to the main view rather than the stack, how can I stop the entire menu shifting up when it expands?

Update:

I have amended the code as follows:

```
 if #available(iOS 14.0.0, *) {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: DataUnitDropDown())
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        controller.view.clipsToBounds = false
        controller.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22).isActive = true
        controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackSubviews = [inputField, controller.view]
    }
```

Now, without the topAnchor constraint this works perfectly, but I do need this constraint. But I get an error due to the views. not being in the same hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

I assume instead of

```
controller.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
       refuelInfoView.actualUpliftVolume.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

you need

```
controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
       refuelInfoView.actualUpliftVolume.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, what a stupid mistake :/ Would you happen to know if there is any feasible way of adding this to a stackview without impacting on the height of the stack when expanded? I wondered about using overlay somehow but couldn't figure it out

Comment: Try to fix height constraint with required priority and set `clipsToBounds` to false, so injected dropdown view would be visible... however not sure it would work in all cases, you see any kind of system menu (context, popup) are issues external to originated view.

Comment: Aha, getting there. So I've updated the post above. It's so close to working, but the problem I have now is that I'm unable to pin this to the current view's constraints as I get an error re not in the same hierarchy, frustrating!